# How to capture digits in front of specific keyword in bash

Tags: bash, sed

Imagine following string:

```
<tr><td>12,3</td><td>deg</td><td>23,4</td><td>humi</td><td>34,5</td><td>press</td></tr>
```

In bash, how do I extract `23.4`, based on the condition that it is followed by `humi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -o` works well for this sort of thing. I'm sure performance would be better with a single sed command than two greps but that's rarely a serious concern.

```sh
X='<tr><td>12,3</td><td>deg</td><td>23,4</td><td>humi</td><td>34,5</td><td>press</td></tr>'
echo $X | grep -o '[0-9,.]*</td><td>humi' | grep -o '[0-9,.]*'
# Result: 23,4
```

You can additionally pipe through `tr , .` to get English number format.

Comment: Even though I was really interested in how this could have been done with one regex, this seems to do the job quite nicely, thanks!